# PDO Fatal Error update

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pdo

I'm receiving this error and it's got me scratching my head:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid
>   data source name' in
>   /Users/aaronwilson/Desktop/testing_server/ATOM_CMS/functions/sandbox.php:10
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Users/aaronwilson/Desktop/testing_server/ATOM_CMS/functions/sandbox.php(10):
>   PDO->__construct('SELECT title FR...') #1
>   /Users/aaronwilson/Desktop/testing_server/ATOM_CMS/config/setup.php(30):
>   get_title(NULL, 'blog') #2
>   /Users/aaronwilson/Desktop/testing_server/ATOM_CMS/index.php(2):
>   include('/Users/aaronwil...') #3 {main} thrown in
>   /Users/aaronwilson/Desktop/testing_server/ATOM_CMS/functions/sandbox.php
>   on line 10

Here's the sandbox.php code:

```
<?php ## Sandbox PHP/PDO Functions 
function get_page($dbc, $pg) {
$sql = new PDO("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page = '$pg' AND status = 1 LIMIT 1");
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
echo '<h1>'.$page['title'].'</h1>';
echo '<div class="content">'.$page['body'].'</div>';}
function get_title($dbc, $pg)  
$sql = new PDO("SELECT title FROM pages WHERE page = '$pg' AND status = 1   LIMIT 1");
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
return $page['title'];}
?>
```

On Setup.php there is a S_GET function to pull the url to call the function on sandbox.php:

```
if ($_GET ['page'] == '') {
$pg = 'home';} 
else {
$pg = $_GET ['page']; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new PDO("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page = '$pg' AND status = 1 LIMIT 1");
```

That's not how you create a PDO object, its parameters are different, it does not take in a query. Following is the constructor prototype.

> public PDO::__construct() ( string $dsn [, string $username [, string $password [, array $driver_options ]]] )

Send parameters to it accordingly. Send `dsn`, `username`, `password`.

**Example from php.net**

```
<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

**[Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)**

Answer (score -1):

Your are not using properly the PDO Library , and thats what causes errors.
Here is an example of one from many correct ways : (Adapt it to your situation and im sure it will help you )

```
$variable1 = "somthing";
$variable2 = "somewhat";
try
  {
    require_once("db-info.php");
    $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname=' . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpassword,     $pdo_options);
    $response = $db->prepare('SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE column1 = :value1 and column2 = :value2');

    $response->execute(array('value1' => $variable1,
                             'value2' => $variable2
                            ));
    $data = $response->fetch(); // works for one set of data 
    // if your are trying to fetch multiple line use a (while $data = $response->fetch())
    //and insert your code inside the while loop.

    //insert your code here....
    //.........................
    //.............
    //using a return true or false may help you with your function case
    $response->closeCursor();
}
catch (Exception $error)

   {

 die('error while selecting data' . $error->getMessage());

   }
```

Comment: thank you for that answer. I'll manipilate your suggested code to fit my variables in it and so forth and see its output when I get home from work.

Comment: Also what about echoing the output to the page. Does that still apply?

Comment: it works the same . but i noticed that you are not declaring your pdo_option .
You gotta do it on each function who uses pdo connexion .
let s say you have tow function doing the same thing , you must repat de same code on each function . And by that i mean you include your data base connexion info and your pdo_options. just try to follow the structure i gave you .
PS : if you have an error with require_once , use include that should work.